# Loading freezes computer when loading web-page using typekit

Tags: google-chrome, browser, typekit

I'm using an MVC web-page,

but when I first load a page using typekit in the browser, the computer freezes for 10 seconds or so. The page loads a large font, which might be causing the freeze.

I'm not sure what is the cause of this, but I think it might be caused by typekit. I've excluded all references to typekit and restarted the computer, I didn't experience the freezing problem. I've done this 3 times. But when I've put the references back, the computer froze on first load of the page again.

Is there anybody who knows what might be causing this? Is this something related to typekit? How can I resolve this issue?

I'm using Windows 7 and I've tested with Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m.

I've also tested the application under FireFox and Internet Explorer, but haven't experienced the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the asynchronous method for loading typekit instead of the synchronous one. Also, check to make sure that you're only loading just the actual fonts you need, not all of them.

http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6852
http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/649336-embed-code